How to add identity in ASP.NET Core using database-first approach
I am building the project in which I created the database tables in SQL Server and then I scaffolded the database, and the DbContext is created after scaffolding.
Now I want to add identity tables like Users, UserRole, Roles, Claim etc using a code-first approach. I remove the DbContext that inherits from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>:
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>

After that I run the commands for add-migration, but I get an error.
If I am doing it with wrong process tell me the correct process to do it

What do you mean by "remove the context"? Simply delete the file or remove all the usage in program and somewhere else. The code-first approach in your description requires a DbContext selfmade, while the database-first approach in the title requires  other more configurations. Please provide more steps of your project to help others understand your issue. Here is a document for you to reference  https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/introduction-to-entity-framework-code-first-approach/   Migration error could be due to coding error, check your ErrorList window to get the error information.
